# recursively find StringCases

Tags: pattern-matching, string-manipulation

Can I recursively extract `StringCases[]` that match a specific pattern?

Here is a minimalist example (not my actual problem):

### input

```
StringCases["car_car_car", "c" ~~ ___ ~~ "r"]
```

### desired output

```
{"car_car_car", "car_car","car","car","car"}
```

### actual output

```
{"car_car_car"}
```

### Question

write a program which recursively searches the string for the pattern

Comment: I think you would like to use the overlaps option: ```StringCases["car_car_car", "c" ~~ ___ ~~ "r", Overlaps -> All]```

Comment: @SHuisman beautiful! just what I was looking for. :)